# The Mad God's Bargain

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

This is the final part of the mage's guild questline so readers beware of spoilers.

> What do I get if I choose to save Valaste, instead of taking the book for the 2 skill points?

P.S. Answerers please us the spoiler tag before any revealing response >!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The only difference between saving Valaste or not saving her is the two skill points. You do not get the points if you save her, and you are not rewarded with anything else for saving her.

Comment: I have to ask, did you actually make the choice? Or did you by chance find it somewhere?

Comment: Either way looks like reddit is upset by it. So thats enough proof for me.